# Proof of the naturality of integration

Tags: differential-geometry, integration, determinant, differential-forms

I have a bit of a problem with the following identity:

Suppose that $U, V \subset \mathbb{R}^n$, are two open sets.
Let $x^1,...,x^n$ be a system of coordinates of $U$ and $y^1,...,y^n$ one on $V$. Let $f:V\rightarrow U$ such that $x^i=f^i(y^1,...,y^n)$. Than:
$$df^1\wedge ... \wedge df^n=\det(\frac{\partial f^i}{\partial y^j})dy^1\wedge...\wedge dy^n.$$

Is this a legal way to prove it?

$df^1\wedge ... \wedge df^n(v_1,...,v_n)=\det(f^i(v_j))=\det(\frac{\partial y^k}{\partial y^k}f^i(v_j))=\det(\frac{\partial f^i}{\partial y^k}y^k(v_j))$ which leads to the result by applying once again the determinant formula.

I have the impression the last equality is wrong or needs to be justified more in details...

Thanks a lot for your precious help and have a nice day!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you try to write out $df^{i}$ in concrete terms, then you will see where the equality comes from.

You should read this [article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pullback_%28differential_geometry%29) carefully.

Comment: if I write $df^i=\frac{\partial f^i}{\partial y^j}d y^j$ I have then a problem as I can't find $dy^1\wedge...\wedge dy^n$ again

Comment: try the 2 by 2 case first.

Comment: I think I got what you told me; We will have all the terms with the a repeating $dy^k=0$ and then the sum of all the permutations which gives the determinant. Is there a more elegant way to put it using the determinant formula instead? thanks a lot

Comment: Notice this is actually the definition of determinant if $f$ happens to be a linear transformation. So you are having tautology at here.

Comment: Ok, but there is no way of getting it by writing the determinant formula as I first suggested it?

Comment: Your "proof" does not make sense as the second equality coming from nowhere. Geometrically this is just the change of variable formula written in a formal way.

Comment: Yes, but once you write $\det(f^i(v_j))$ is it possible to work things out?

Comment: You write $df^{i}=\sum^{n}_{j=1}\frac{\partial f^{i}}{\partial y_{j}}dy_{j}$. This the same as $df^{i}=A_{i}dy$, with $dy=(dy_{1},dy_{2},..,dy_{n})$. Now $\bigwedge A_{i}dy=\det(A)\bigwedge dy_{j}$, where $A=\langle A_{1},A_{2},...,A_{n}\rangle$.